# Me imprime una linea repetida

Tags: c, depuración

buenas!

A la hora de imprimir los valores no se por qué me repite la ultima linea 2 veces:

Aquí les dejo el código :

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(){
        char linea1[100],linea2[100],tab[100],tab1[100],tab2[100],notas[100];
        int i=0;
    FILE *f1;
    f1=fopen("h.txt","r");
    fgets(linea1,100,f1);
    fgets(linea2,100,f1);
    while(!feof(f1)){
        fscanf(f1,"%[^\t] %[^\t] ",tab,notas);
        printf("%s\n",notas);
    }
    }
```

Aqui les dejo el fichero :

```
 Fecha Examen: 2018/08/09
    Numero de pruebas: 6
    23321223D Markel Zubieta    4.47 3.06 5.09 5.11 8.18 7.95 6.44 3.79 8.12 5.33   2000/2/3
    13080976G Antonio Gonzalez Perez    3.51 2.08 3.01 4.71 1943/12/21
    34235676F Jose Luis Martinez Garcia 2.26 1.85 9.05 9.80 4.39    1986/2/29
    X345432Y Victor Mayo    2.58 4.09 5.9 2.6 6.3 7.1 4.24 5.08 2000/11/12
    20205632S Silva Martinez Fernandez  0.86 2.62 8.01 0.9 9.2 7 4.89 5.79 2.37 7   1970/04/10
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu archivo de entrada `h.txt` tiene una línea en blanco al final.

Como está en blanco, `fscanf` no puede extraer los valores pedidos, entonces deja los que estaban antes (los últimos de la lista). Luego tÚ los imprimes -> imprimes dos veces.

**Solución**

`fscanf` retorna el número de valores extraidos. Hay que compararLO contra los valores esperados:

```
if (fscanf(f1,"%[^\t] %[^\t] ",tab,notas) == 2) {
    printf("%s\n",notas);
    }
```